# erlang -import not working

Tags: linux, erlang

I have an erlang program, compiled with rebar, after the new debian release, it won't compile anymore, complaining about this:

```
-import(erl_scan).
-import(erl_parse).
-import(io_lib).
```

saying:

> bad import declaration

I don't know erlang, I am just trying to compile this thing.
Apparently something bad happened to -import recently http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-March/072932.html

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to fix this. The source code has to be updated, and every reference to imported functions prefixed with the module in question.  For example, every call to `format` should be replaced with `io_lib:format`, though you'd have to know which function was imported from which module.

You could start by removing the `-import` directives.  The compilation should then fail, complaining about undefined functions.  That is where you need to provide the correct module name.  Look at the documentation pages for [io_lib](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html), [erl_scan](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_scan.html) and [erl_parse](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html) to see which functions are in which module.

Comment: removing the all imports from all the files seems to be working without other modifications (is it normal?)

Comment: I guess someone cleaned up the code and prefixed all the calls already, but forgot to take out the import directives.

Comment: Note that those import declarations (part of the experimental "packages" that was removed) didn't import specific functions, like the normal -import(ModuleName, [Function1, ..., FunctionN]), but module names, so that "foo" could be used instead of "bar.baz.foo", etc. Importing a name like io_lib just meant that you didn't have to use a leading dot to denote the "empty" namespace as in .io_lib. And if the containing module was not in itself in a package (maybe it was, once, and then got renamed again), the imports had no effect anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Well, `-import().` is working but it does **NOT** do what you are expecting it to do. It does **NOT** "import" the module into your module, nor does it go out, find the module and get all the exported functions and allow you to use them without the module name. You use `-import` like this:

```
-import(lists, [map/2,foldl/3,foldr/3]).
```

Then you can call the explicitly imported functions without module name and the compiler syntactically transforms the call by adding the module name. So the compiler will transform:

```
map(MyFun, List) ===> lists:map(MyFun, List)
```

Note that this is **ALL** it does. There are no checks for whether the module exists or if the function is exported, it is a pure naive syntactic transformation. All it gives you is slightly shorter code. For this reason it is seldom used most people advise not to use it.

Note also that the unit of code for all operations is the module so the compiler does not do any inter-module checking or optimisation at all. Everything *between modules* like checking a modules existence or which functions it exports is done at run-time when you call a function in the other module.

Comment: Yes i understood what it does. I didn't write that code and I was just trying to make it work, and if removing the import it works, apparently the name transformation was not used anyway I suppose

Comment: and anyway if rebar fails I'd say that import is not working.

Comment: @LtWorf it depends what you mean by not working. The examples you gave were **illegal syntax** which is what the compiler was complaining about. So it never got as far as actually trying do some importing. Rebar doesn't do anything special in this case, it uses the normal erlang parser and compiler, so it failed because the illegal syntax caused the parser and compiler to fail.

Comment: what baffled me was that it worked perfectly 1 month ago and today running rebar again it didn't. By working I mean that you can run the program using erl and it does what it should.

Comment: @LtWorf that is strange because that syntax has always been illegal. What version are you running? Have you changed version in-between?

Comment: Yes erlang was updated in debian on the 2nd week of may. It had 15 and now it's 16.

Comment: @LtWorf the answer by @IGIVECRAPANSWERS explains why `-import(Mod).` was illegal and is now illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you were using the experimental `-import(Mod)` directive which is part of parameterized modules. These are gone in R16B and onwards.

I often advise against using import. It hurts quick searches and unique naming of foreign calls. Get an editor which can quickly expand names.

Comment: Thank you, I had avoided parametrised modules :-) so I had missed the `-import(Mod).` construct.

Answer (score -3):

Start by looking at what is stored in the location `$ERL_LIBS`, typically this points to /usr/lib/erlang/lib.

Comment: the compilation was working fine until dist-upgrade happened, the modules are present on the system

Comment: I understand that, that's why I was trying to see if the modules had been removed or renamed duringthe upgrade