# Passing list to function results in no case clause matching

Tags: recursion, erlang

I am attempting to pass a list into a function and I am just now learning erlang. So I am new. I get this error in my shell when I attempt to build my erl file.

```
exception error: no case clause matching [{atom,{3,9},lists}]
  in function  erl_parse:build_attribute/2 (erl_parse.yrl, line 1395)
  in call from erl_parse:yeccpars2_654/7 (erl_parse.yrl, line 127)
  in call from erl_parse:yeccpars0/5 (/daily_build/otp_src/bootstrap/lib/parsetools/include/yeccpre.hrl, line 57)
  in call from epp:parse_file/1 (epp.erl, line 364)
  in call from epp:parse_file/1 (epp.erl, line 366)
  in call from epp:parse_file/2 (epp.erl, line 337)
  in call from compile:do_parse_module/2 (compile.erl, line 1037)
  in call from compile:parse_module/2 (compile.erl, line 1011)
```

Here is my code that is causing it.

It is in my for function, the rest of the code is just test work as I am practicing.

```
 % hello world program
-module(helloworld).
-import(lists).
-import(io,[fwrite/1]).
-export([start/0,greet/2,for/3]). 


greet(male, Name) ->
    io:format("Hello, Mr. ~s!\n", [Name]);
    greet(female, Name) ->
    io:format("Hello, Mrs. ~s!\n", [Name]);
    greet(_, Name) ->
    io:format("Hello, ~s!\n", [Name]).

for(Nums <- [H|T], Idx, Target) ->
    Val = lists:nth(Idx, Nums),
    S = if Val == Target -> Idx;
       Idx >= len(Nums) -> -1;
       true -> for(Nums, Idx + 1, Target);
    end,
    S.
    
   

start() -> 
   fwrite("Hello, world!\n").
```

Also, I am curious that is actually going to return recursively.

Comment: You  have an error in `if` statement. It should be in the form `if  cond -> statement1;  true -> statement2;`

Comment: Okay. I have updated my code above to reflect changes. I am still getting the same error, but I believe my `if` is now correct.

Comment: Few more things `-compile` has  2 arguments. And also`for((Nums <- [H|T],..` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
-import(lists).
```

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16810643/113848), the one-argument form of the `-import` directive was removed in Erlang R16B (released in 2013).  These days `-import` directives require two arguments, the module name and a list of functions to import, like the one on the line below:

```
-import(io,[fwrite/1]).
```

In general, importing functions is discouraged in Erlang. It is often clearer to include the module name every time you're calling a function. For example, when reading the `start` function:

```
start() -> 
   fwrite("Hello, world!\n").
```

the call to `fwrite` looks like a local function call, and it's only by looking at the `-import` directive that you realise that it's actually a call to `io:fwrite`.

So I would recommend removing *both* `-import` directives, and changing the `start` function to call `io:fwrite` explicitly, like this:

```
start() -> 
   io:fwrite("Hello, world!\n").
```

Answer (score 3):

> Also, I am curious that is actually going to return recursively.

It looks that you want to find the index ofelement of list `Nums` that is equal to `Target` if such exists and return `-1` otherwise. Something like this.

```
-module(find).
-export([find/2, start/0]).

find([H|T], Target) -> f([H|T], Target, 0).

f([], _, _) ->  -1;  % not found 

f([H|T], Target, Idx) -> 
    if 
        H == Target -> Idx;  % found
        true -> f(T, Target, Idx+1) % keep searching
    end 
.

start() -> 
    io:fwrite("~w~n", [find([1, 2, 3], 3)]),
    io:fwrite("~w~n", [find([1, 2, 3], 5)]).
```

Output.

```
2
-1
ok
```

**UPD**
Answering the questions from comments.
Let's look how we call `f` function looking for target `5`.

```
f([1, 2, 3], 5, 0)
f([2, 3], 5, 1)
f([3], 5, 2)
f([], 5, 3)
```

Last call matches `f([], _, _)` and returns `-1`. So no indexing occurs and no "index out of range" happens.

But if you try to call `lists:nth(4, [1, 2, 3])` you will get something like

```
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:nth(1,[]) (lists.erl, line 170)
```

Comment: This is very nice and I would upvote if I had score. I will ask how does this handle an index out of range exception assuming that exists in Erlang? If not, I understand I still have more erlang to learn if idx out of range for a list is not a worry.